# Can I rename Dogmeat?

Tags: fallout-4

As much as I like the original Fallout, I can think of a few better names for my dog than Dogmeat. Is it possible to rename Dogmeat, either in-game or through the console?

Comment: Why does the question reference the original Fallout instead of Fallout 4?

Comment: @Stevoisiak I believe OP is referencing the [dog player companion in the original Fallout, whose name is also Dogmeat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogmeat_(Fallout))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to find one solution, which is easy, if not quite ideal. Since this involves file manipulation, it won't work on consoles. Also any patches might wipe it out, but you can always just change it back if that happens.

1. Navigate to `steamapps/common/Fallout 4/Data/Strings`. This folder contains all the messages that appear in the game.
2. Make a backup copy of the three files in this folder, `Fallout4_en.DLSTRINGS`, `Fallout4_en.ILSTRINGS`, and `Fallout4_en.STRINGS`.
3. Use your favourite text editor to replace the word "Dogmeat" with whatever you want Dogmeat to be called. Do this in each of the three files.
4. Enjoy your newly-named dog, though anyone who talks about him in dialog will still call him Dogmeat. Rude.

[image: Way to go, Maulkin.]

Comment: I tried that my game crashed. Maybe I did it wrong. I took the files and changed each instance of Dogmeat to Eric with the search and replace function. Where did I mess up?